# asp.net Obtener atributos de pagina a través de su url

Tags: asp.net

Tengo varios webforms creados con atributos personalizados de esta forma:

```
NombreObjeto("WFEDICIONPERMISOS_SA")
Public Class sa_Permisos
Inherits PageBaseClass
    Protected Sub Page_Load....
```

Ahora tengo una zona de administracion desde la que quiero consultar todos los webforms de una carpeta y leer su atributo para identificar al webform por su codigo (en el atributo).

Tengo ya la forma de consultar los archivos de la carpeta pero necesitaria obtener un objeto Page desde la ruta fisica del archivo o de cualquier otra forma.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que podrías usar el método [GetCompiledType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getcompiledtype(v=vs.110).aspx) de la clase `BuildManager` (System.Web.Compilation) para obtener el tipo de la página y extraer los atributos a partir de el.

El código sería así:

```
'Obtener el tipo correspondiente a la página
Dim pageType As Type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/Page1.aspx")

'Obtener el atrubuto personalizado
Dim attr As NombreObjetoAttribute = pageType.GetCustomAttribute(Of NombreObjetoAttribute)()
```

Comment: gracias rscirano, ¿es posible que sea necesario cambiar los niveles de acceso de variables y objetos dentro del webform compilado de esta forma? me lanza un error referente al nivel de proteccion de un Label dentro del primer form y me temo que lo va a seguir mostrando para el resto de forms

Comment: finalmente era error del nombre de archivo que estaba enviando como virtualpath